# Retrieving Data From Server Android

Tags: android, database

I need to make an app, that it android based.

What I need to do is as follows:

1) A user Logins in to the app (Server);
2) A Chat Menu is shown with users that are connedted;
3) when the user connects the server checks to see if he is single(don't mind this if statment);
4) if the user is single a green icon is add'd next to his nickname;

I just need to to know the basic guidline to do such a thing, Do I need a database on the server?, if so can you direct me to a good tutorial about such thing?

any help would be more than good for me.

Kind Reggards

Boaz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the simplest way to do this is to use a server that keeps track of the states of the logged in users. Your question is not Android specific, and you could e.g. use a general Java based solution modified to fit your needs. [Here is a simple example/tutorial.](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html)

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to set it as the accepted answer if you feel that it answers your question.